# I am getting Error: Type 'Completer' not found. when using flutter Webview plugin

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutterwebviewplugin

I am trying to add webpage to my flutter website and getting this error
code: Web_view.dart

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwZQA.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFaYs.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use completers, you need to `import the dart:async`

Comment: Thanks It worked but now I am getting Unsupported operation  this error  "Trying to use the default webview implementation for TargetPlatform.windows but there isn't a default one"               Flutter new versions doesnot support webview for windows but I want to display website is there any solution

Comment: can you please mark the answer as it works for you first? and then you need to ask this one as a new question, thanks